# NodeJS showing documents by timestamps with delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

I have 6 user tiers. This is what they should do:

- 1st tier: See posts immediately that are being posted.
- 2nd tier: See the same post **after 60 minutes**
- 3rd tier: See the same post **after 120 minutes**
- 4th tier: See the same post **after 240 minutes**
- 5th tier: See the same post **after 360 minutes**
- 6th tier: See the same post **after 24 hours**

Every users get their `tier` setup when they register on the site.

Now when someone post a data to the website this is how the document structure in mongoose looks like:

[image]

For timestamps that you see I'm using moment.js and just plain function: `moment();` All timestamps here are set when the users tiers should see the post.

Now I need to fetch those documents by the authenticated user tier. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    if(req.session.user && req.cookies.user_sid){
        let user = await User.findOne({username:req.session.user.username});
        if(user.group = "Tier 1") {
            let advertisements = await Advertisement.find();
            res.render('index', {user, advertisements});
             // TIER 1 SEES ALL POSTS IMMEDIATELY.
        }
        if(user.group = "Tier 2") {
            let advertisements = await Advertisement.find();
            // Now I need some logic here so the tier 2 users could see post after 60 minutes from when it was posted.
            res.render('index', {user, advertisements});
        }        
    } else {
    res.render('index');
    }
});
```

I don't know how to fetch the results from `tier 2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find more success with storing the time every advertisement was added into the system - that way you can modify the filter on the Advertisement objects based on the `tier` of the User:

```
// Imagine the following Advertisements:
[
  {
    "name": "ad-1",
    "created_at": ISODate(2019-02-01)
  },
  {
    "name": "ad-2",
    "created_at": ISODate(2019-02-25)
  }
]

let offset;
if (user.group === "Tier-1") {
  offset = 0;
} else if (user.group === "Tier-2" {
  offset = 60 * 60 // remember, it's in seconds!
} else if (user.group === "Tier-3" {
  ....
}

const now = Date.now();

await db.Users.find({
  "created_at" < (now - offset)
});
```